# Retrieve secrets from Azure KeyVault using Blazor wasm

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor, azure-keyvault

I need help to retrieve secrets from azure key vault and display them in my razor page.
I have a web client and a web server side. On my controller, i have done this :

```
[ApiController]
    public class SecretController : Controller
    {
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        //public string SecretValue { get; set; }

        public SecretController(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        //public void OnGet() //Task<IActionResult> OnGet() //A automatiser
        //{
        //SecretValue = Configuration["test"];

        //}
        [HttpGet("secrets")]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            return Ok(new { Secret = Configuration.GetValue<string>("test") });
        }
```

Which works and return me a status 200 with a json string : {"secret":"valueofthesecret"}.

I want to display this value in my razor file, but I need to retrieve the data from the status in my razor.cs file client sided.

For the moment, i tried something like this but it doesn't work :

```
public partial class Secrets : ComponentBase
{
        public const string Url1 = "/secrets";
        //public string secret { get; set; }
        private Secrets[] LSecrets;

        protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync() =>
            LSecrets = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<Secrets[]>("secrets");
}
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: Your code on the razor side is wrong, you can't set an array from a JSON object return type. You need to adjust your controller to return an array OR change the client to be a single object.

Comment: Yeah i'm working on it, i had a lot of things missing in my controller. I'll post when I achieve that